# "hadoop fs -mkdir" permission denied despite being in the correct group

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create a folder in HDFS from the command line with a user different from `hdfs`. The directory has permissions `775` for `hdfs:hdfs`:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
... directories ...
drwxrwxr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2018-02-21 11:37 /data
... more directories
```

My user is in the group `hdfs`:

```
$ cat /etc/group
hdfs:x:nnnn:myusername
```

However, when I do `hadoop fs -mkdir /data/foo` I get:

```
mkdir: Permission denied: user=myusername, access=WRITE, inode="/data/foo":hdfs:hdfs:drwxrwxr-x
```

Does `hdfs` have to be my primary group for this?

Comment: Check the groups on the namenode. Not your local machine (if separate). That's where the accounts are checked.

Comment: I now added this user and put it in the `hdfs` group on the namenode but am still getting permission denied.

Comment: In my experience, that should work if the cluster isn't kerberized. Do you have two namenodes?

Comment: I have a secondary namenode. I'll try adding the user to both later.

Comment: In addition to what @cricket_007 said, also run `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshUserToGroupsMappings` to refresh the user-group mapping on the NameNode(s)

Comment: Standby namenode is not the same as a "secondary namenode"